# What is the most efficient way to find all files containing given string, case-insensitive using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder with many subfolders and 1000+ text files (50-200mb per file) on different levels, and I want to find which files contain a particular string (regardless of the casing).

How to implement this **for best performance** ? (python3.6.5+)

The task can be decomposed in to two sub-tasks:

- Get all the files in the folder.
- Check which files contain the string (case-insensitive).

For the first task (*Get all the files in the folder*) I've written benchmark for couple of approaches to do it, and the results are below:

```
# test_get_files.py
from glob import glob
from os import walk
from os.path import isfile, join
from timeit import timeit

from tabulate import tabulate

FOLDER = r"/path/to/dir/with/many/nested/files"


def get_files_using_walk_top_down_list(folder):
    return [join(parent, file)
            for parent, _, filenames in walk(folder, topdown=True)
            for file in filenames]


def get_files_using_walk_top_down_tuple(folder):
    return tuple(join(parent, file)
                 for parent, _, filenames in walk(folder, topdown=True)
                 for file in filenames)


def get_files_using_walk_top_down_set(folder):
    return {join(parent, file)
            for parent, _, filenames in walk(folder, topdown=True)
            for file in filenames}


def get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_list(folder):
    return [join(parent, file)
            for parent, _, filenames in walk(folder, topdown=False)
            for file in filenames]


def get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_tuple(folder):
    return tuple(join(parent, file)
                 for parent, _, filenames in walk(folder, topdown=False)
                 for file in filenames)


def get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_set(folder):
    return {join(parent, file)
            for parent, _, filenames in walk(folder, topdown=False)
            for file in filenames}


def get_files_using_glob_list(folder):
    return [path
            for path in glob(f"{folder}/**/*", recursive=True)
            if isfile(path)]


def get_files_using_glob_tuple(folder):
    return tuple(path
                 for path in glob(f"{folder}/**/*", recursive=True)
                 if isfile(path))


def get_files_using_glob_set(folder):
    return {path
            for path in glob(f"{folder}/**/*", recursive=True)
            if isfile(path)}


def benchmark(func, folder, number):
    return timeit(stmt=f"{func.__name__}('{folder}')",
                  setup=f"from test_get_files import {func.__name__}",
                  number=number)


def main():
    funcs = (get_files_using_glob_list,
             get_files_using_glob_tuple,
             get_files_using_glob_set,
             get_files_using_walk_top_down_list,
             get_files_using_walk_top_down_tuple,
             get_files_using_walk_top_down_set,
             get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_list,
             get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_tuple,
             get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_set)
    numbers = (100, 500, 1000)
    results = []
    for number in numbers:
        results.extend([(func.__name__, number, benchmark(func, FOLDER, number)) for func in funcs])
    print(tabulate(results, headers="FUNC_NAME NUMBER TOOK".split()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is:

```
FUNC_NAME                               NUMBER      TOOK
------------------------------------  --------  --------
get_files_using_glob_list                  100  0.945687
get_files_using_glob_tuple                 100  0.852411
get_files_using_glob_set                   100  0.861514
get_files_using_walk_top_down_list         100  0.320643
get_files_using_walk_top_down_tuple        100  0.326478
get_files_using_walk_top_down_set          100  0.33721
get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_list        100  0.28824
get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_tuple       100  0.295585
get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_set         100  0.304363
get_files_using_glob_list                  500  4.23723
get_files_using_glob_tuple                 500  4.2692
get_files_using_glob_set                   500  4.30241
get_files_using_walk_top_down_list         500  1.59499
get_files_using_walk_top_down_tuple        500  1.62841
get_files_using_walk_top_down_set          500  1.67612
get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_list        500  1.43197
get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_tuple       500  1.45971
get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_set         500  1.51071
get_files_using_glob_list                 1000  8.42451
get_files_using_glob_tuple                1000  8.61827
get_files_using_glob_set                  1000  8.60752
get_files_using_walk_top_down_list        1000  3.18595
get_files_using_walk_top_down_tuple       1000  3.24857
get_files_using_walk_top_down_set         1000  3.35619
get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_list       1000  2.86118
get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_tuple      1000  2.92635
get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_set        1000  3.01853
```

I think there's not much place for further improvement of how the files are collected.

get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_list wins the race.

Now for the second task (*Check which files contain the string (case-insensitive)*), Since when reading the complete file contents before doing the check, there is constant overhead of physically reading all bytes in the file, checking the file line-by-line and breaking the loop upon first matching line seems the most reasonable way to do it.

Here is the benchmark code for checking the files in different ways:

```
# search_showcase.py
from os import walk
from os.path import join
from random import choice, randint
from timeit import timeit

from tabulate import tabulate


def get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_list(folder):
    return [join(parent, file)
            for parent, _, filenames in walk(folder, topdown=False)
            for file in filenames]


def check_using_in(file, text):
    with open(file, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if text in line.lower():
                return True
    return False


def check_using_index(file, text):
    with open(file, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            try:
                line.lower().index(text)
            except:
                continue
            else:
                return True
    return False


def check_using_find(file, text):
    with open(file, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if line.lower().find(text) != -1:
                return True
    return False


def get_files(files, check_func, text):
    return [file
            for file
            in files
            if check_func(file, text)]


def benchmark(func, files, text, number):
    return timeit(stmt=f"get_files({files}, {func.__name__}, '{text}')",
                  setup=f"from search_showcase import get_files, {func.__name__}",
                  number=number)


def main():
    text = "not-so-common-word"
    folder = r"/path/to/files/dir"
    funcs = (check_using_in, check_using_find, check_using_index)

    # using some instead all files to reduce execution time
    all_files = get_files_using_walk_bottom_up_list(folder)
    some_files = [choice(all_files) for _ in range(randint(25, 50))]
    print(f"selected {len(some_files)} of {len(all_files)} files\n")

    # ensure the funcs discover same files before doing the benchmark
    results_by_func = {func: get_files(some_files, func, text) for func in funcs}
    assert (results_by_func[check_using_in] == results_by_func[check_using_find] == results_by_func[check_using_index])

    # print the count of results to get some credibility
    details = {func.__name__: len(results) for func, results in results_by_func.items()}
    print(tabulate(tabular_data=[details], headers="keys"))

    # do the benchmark
    numbers = (5, 10)
    benchmark_results = []
    for number in numbers:
        benchmark_results.extend(
            [(func.__name__, number, benchmark(func, some_files, text, number)) for func in funcs])

    # print the results
    print(tabulate(benchmark_results, headers="FUNC_NAME NUMBER TOOK".split()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is the output:

```
selected 41 of 764 files

  check_using_in    check_using_find    check_using_index
----------------  ------------------  -------------------
              13                  13                   13
FUNC_NAME            NUMBER      TOOK
-----------------  --------  --------
check_using_in            5  0.475356
check_using_find          5  0.678626
check_using_index         5  1.23154
check_using_in           10  0.941205
check_using_find         10  1.35866
check_using_index        10  2.4155
```

Can you tell me if there is any faster way to write this check (without using milti-threading/processing)?

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, where you can spec out a function and ask people to write it for you. For that you usually need to pay programmers! If you offer one (or more) solution, then perhaps we can compare that to other approaches to help you find the one with the best performance. But as it is, this question seems like you're just asking people to do your work for you.

Comment: I tought that it's meaningless to post the implementation as everyone can do it, but just because of your comment ill post mine so we can have some grounding

Comment: The most efficient way is probably to use `os.system` to run `grep`.

Comment: This might be true on Linux, but it won't work on Windows

Comment: Kindly asking the admins to reopen the question as there is still lot more to duscuss on the topic.

Comment: `findstr` is the `grep` for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a perfect use case for multiprocessing module. Inside the process function, you can open the file do readlines(), check if string exists and return if string exists.

Comment: I've tried doing something similar for checking single file (sorry but formatting is not workin in comments):  for line in open(file, mode="r"): if text in line.lower(): return true